# Combine inline jquery datepicker with an input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I know that I can use `$('div').datepicker()` to get an inline datepicker, but how do I show the `datepicker` fixed inline underneath its input field?

The `alt` field option does not work for me because I want the `datepicker` to also react on a date entered into the input field.

I would need something like the following pseudocode:

```
<inputfield type="text" id="d" >
<div id="z"></div>  
<script> $('#z').datepicker().bindToInputfield($('#d')) </script>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/KRFCH/

The `altField` option will link to the second field you want! http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field

Now note: any change in the input will reflect in the datepicker on `change`

This should fit your cause `:)`

**Code**

```
$('#z').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    altField: '#d'
});

$('#d').change(function(){
    $('#z').datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible to get the `datepicker` inline just by using the `input` field . You need to use a `div` along with an `input` to get what you want.

**NOTE:** Any changes made in the `input` will reflect in the `datepicker`

**Example Code**

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
$('#mydiv').datepicker();

$('#text').change(function(){
    $('#mydiv').datepicker('setDate', $(this).val());
});
$('#mydiv').change(function(){
    $('#text').attr('value',$(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Check out this jsfiddle I've created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/v9XCP/