# jquery mobile datepicker doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-ui, datepicker

Hi can someone tell me why the following jquery mobile datepicker doesnt work as i directly copied from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and the following is a screenshot of my problem. It only showed a text field for the datepicker. Initially i thought it was a browser issue but it works on none of the browser and also including the phonegap platform i am currently using.[Example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5J5m.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works! I think that the problem is another one:

> From http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/

You have **Popup Datepicker**

```
<input type="text" data-role="date">
```

and **Inline Datepicker**

```
<input type="text" data-role="date" data-inline="true">
```

The Popup does not always position well for use on small screens and mobile devices there for the wrapper adds an inline option this option makes the calendar for the datepicker show up inline after the input which it is called on avoiding the issues related to popups.

Documentation about Datepicker widget: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Information and support on the jQuery Mobile Wrapper: https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper

For more information about **datepicker inline and how to use** it take a look at this question: **[Combine inline jquery datepicker with an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344135/combine-inline-jquery-datepicker-with-an-input-field)** that explain how to use:

```
$(function(){
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
    })
})
```